# How to change/add view to rootcontroller's view in UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application where I need to have a "custom" setting page. In my delegate I add a UINavigationController's view to the window with a UIViewController as rootviewcontroller.

In the rootviewcontroller I want to have a button and when I press the button the whole view changes to the settingview that I made. I only need the code to change view.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Settings View a UIView SubClass then In the Button Action method you can do something like this:

> [self.view addChild: settingsView]; //provided that settingsView is already allocated.

If you have written down a separate UIViewController SubClass for Settings then you can do something like this in your Button Action Method:

```
SettingsViewController *controller=[[SettingsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

Comment: On my simulator this works
[self.view.window addSubview:svc.view];  
//this code is in my root view controller

However on my iPhone it doesn't work.

Comment: well, just stick with "self.view" instead of "self.view.window"

Comment: Does not work as intended nor on iPhone.

I have an application that are based on UINavigationController. The UINavigationControllers view is added to the window in appdelegate. The navigationController is initialized with a normal UIViewController.

So when I launch the application it is a blue bar with the rootcontroller view. What I have…and want is to have an button in the rootcontroller's view that a user can tap. When he/she does that the whole screen changes to another navigation controllers view. This will be the "in-app-setting view".

I have to BREAK UP MY COMMENT... read further.

Comment: SettingsViewController *svc = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc initWithRootViewController:svc];
 
[self.view.window addSubview:svc.view];

The strange thing is that this code works on the iPhone simulator but NOT on the device???

Any idea?

Comment: Ok, I think you are confusing Navigation with SubViews. If you have your UINavigationController initialized in your app delegate then you don't need to re-initialize it again from the RootViewController. Now, In the RootViewController's button action method, you just have to grab a reference to the NavigationController and PUSH the SettingsViewController like i described in my original post (the 2nd snippet). You don't need to AddSubviews if you have separate UIViewController SubClasses for each View. If you still can't get it done, do post your code here.

Comment: Some weeks later I got the desired behaviour working, however not exactly as you mention because you didn`t fully understand my question. Thanks for the help though and I accept you answer.